# How to use jQuery in global imported functions without jQuery.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript

my code in JS is getting very large right now and so I wanted to outsource sections to other files, for clarity.

In my main file I use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $.getScript("/wp-content/plugins/file2.js",function(){
        console.log("loaded 2");
    });
    $.getScript("/wp-content/plugins/file3.js",function(){
        console.log("loaded 3");
    });
```

This works.
In file 2 and 3 I use jQuery with functions like:

```
function getData(){
$.("#foo").on("click", function(){});
}
```

So I am getting the error

```
$ is undefined
```

because I do not declare $.
But if I wrap around the $.ready function I can't access the functions inside file 2 which are used by the other files.

How can I 'declare' the $ separately without loosing the global scope of the function. Or is there even a better way?
I only include in html:

```
<script src="/wp-content/plugins/file1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: _"and so I wanted to outsource sections to other files, for clarity"_ - but why does that mean that you need to trigger the _loading_ of those scripts via client-side JS now? What is stopping you from still adding them to the head or footer via the usual `wp_enqueue_script`?

Comment: `$.("#foo")` is a typo. It's just `$("#foo")`

Comment: You can re-redefine `jQuery` as `$`, so in your file2 `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);` (assuming jquery.js is included before file2) but if you put your function `function getData()` it will no longer be global - the answer is don't use global functions.

Answer (score 1):

A copy of `jQuery` is assigned to `$` **by default**.

It will only be undefined if you:

- Overwrite it
- Mask it
- Call [`$.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

… so don't do any of those.